# Nodejs "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Tags: node.js, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a Bitcoin insight explorer (https://www.dgbwiki.com/index.php?title=Running_your_own_Insight_explorer). Using node v0.10.48 but I get this error (couldn't find the same problem over the internet):

```
digibyte@derecha-virtual-machine:~/insight$ /home/digibyte/.nvm/v0.10.48/bin/node ~/insight/node_modules/insight-bitcore-api/util/sync.js -D -v --rpc

/home/digibyte/insight/node_modules/insight-bitcore-api/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:52
    function apply(fn, ...args) {
                       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/digibyte/insight/node_modules/insight-bitcore-api/lib/HistoricSync.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

The offending line 52 is in this function:

```
function apply(fn, ...args) { // <- line 52
    return (...callArgs) => fn(...args,...callArgs);
}
```

It looks ok to me I don't know why node gives an error.

Comment: Which IDE( eg. VS Code) are you using?

Comment: Is not my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-rest-parameters, node v0.10.48 does not support rest parameters (`...args`).

You should use a newer version of node (at least v6.4.0 as default support, or at least v4.9.1 with `--harmony` flag (`node --harmony`))

Answer (score 2):

Node.js 0.10.48 doesn't support the spread operator. The first Node.js version to support the spread operator was 5, but it's quite outdated and isn't maintained anymore. If you're already upgrading, I'd upgrade to one of the newer version still supported under LTS.

Answer (score -1):

Apply takes an array as the second argument. Here, the `spread` operator (`...`) is laying out the elements, and thus you don't pass an array into the function, but basically comma separated arguments.

Try using `.call` instead of `.apply`, or pass `args` instead of `...args`.